# Definition f the $\sigma -$algebra product.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F) $ a measure space. There are several definition for the product $\Omega ^{\mathcal J}=\prod_{j\in \mathcal J}\Omega _j$ where $\Omega _j$ is a copy of $\Omega $.

Let $\pi_j: \Omega ^{\mathcal J}\to  \Omega_j $ the projection on $\Omega _j$, i.e. $\pi_j((x_j)_{j\in\mathcal J})=x_j$. In some book the define $\mathcal F^{\otimes J}$ as $$\sigma \{\pi^{-1}_j(B)\mid B\in \mathcal F, j\in \mathcal J\},$$

and in others books, it's like $\mathcal F^{\otimes \mathcal J}=\sigma (\mathcal C)$ where $\mathcal C$ is the collection of cylinder $$C_{j_1,...,j_n}(B_1,...,B_n)=\{x\in \Omega ^{\mathcal J}\mid x_{j_1}\in B_1,...,x_{j_n}\in B_n\}.$$

The first one makes sens for me, but I admitt that I have some problem to understand the second definition... I'm not sure to really understand what it mean.

---

According to Surb answer, why don't we define $$\mathcal F^{\otimes \mathcal J}=\sigma \left\{\prod_{j\in \mathcal J}A_j\mid A_j\in \mathcal F\ \forall j\in\mathcal J\right\} \ \ ?$$
i.e., we don't suppose that $A_j\neq \Omega $ for finite numbers of $j$.

Answer (score 1):

$C_{j_1,...,j_n}(B_1,...,B_n)$ is nothing else than $\pi^{-1}_{j_1}(B_1)\cap...\cap \pi_{j_n}^{-1}(B_n)$. In other words, $$\sigma (\mathcal C)=\sigma \left\{\prod_{j\in \mathcal J}A_j\mid A_j\neq \Omega \text{ for a finite number of $j$ and } A_j\in \mathcal F,\forall j\in\mathcal J\right\}.$$

If you pay attention to this definition, it looks like the definition of the topology product... well, the idea is the same. Now, an exercise would be to prove that $$\sigma \{\pi_j^{-1}(B)\mid j\in\mathcal J, B\in \mathcal F\}=\sigma (\mathcal C).$$

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Comment: For a stochastic process, it's enough to know the finite dimensional law to know the distribution of the process (Kolmogorov extension theorem). So it's not necessary to have more information...